# Drush 8 not working correctly on (LAMP) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: database, drush

I am running LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04.  I have a drupal 7 installation and I have installed drush 8.1.3 via Composer version 1.5.2. I believe there is bug in [php7.2 causing the error](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3226) as discussed on Github, however even after I applied the recommended fix which is to update the pear/console_table to the latest version [instructed here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/php-console-table), the problem still remains. I also followed the instructions on [Super User](https://superuser.com) to be absolutely sure that I have [the most up to date version of pear](https://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu) installed as well (did not install PHPunit).  And, FYI in accordance with the [drush installation documentation found here](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/), I also made the proper changes to my `.bashrc` file as well (below).

Whenever I run `drush status` I receive the following error:

[**UPDATE:** This part of problem **SOLVED** by [@GiorgosK](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/68569/giorgosk) answer below.  Other problems persist due to Drush not find mysql socket]

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                 
PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini                     
PHP OS                 :  Linux                                        
Drush script           :  /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php 
Drush version          :  8.1.13                                       
Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                         
Drush configuration    :                                               
Drush alias files      :
```

If I execute `drush sql-connect`

```
Unable to load class Drush\Sql\Sql                                  [error]
Drush\Sql\SqlException: Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush   [error]
cannot find your database connection details. in
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:541
Stack trace:
#0
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(221):
drush_sql_get_class()
#1 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422):
drush_sql_connect()
#2 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#3 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199):
drush_command()
#4
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#5 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#6 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#7 {main}
```

The contents of my `~/.bashrc` file, are as follows:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

# Include Drush bash customizations.
if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.bashrc" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.bashrc
fi

# Include Drush completion.

if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.complete.sh" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.complete.sh
fi

# Include Drush prompt customizations.

if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.prompt.sh" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.prompt.sh
fi
```

The result of `drush cc all` executed from within my drupal installation folder is:

```
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.
```

Anyone know how to get drush to working for my local (LAMP) Drupal 7 installations?

thx

Comment: Try putting `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @christia thx for the reply.  Haven't had a chance to try this yet b/c an update to mysql crashed all of my lamp drupal sites.  I now need to post my new problem, then return to this... but I'll be sure to let u know if your suggestion helps

Comment: State clearly what part is still giving you trouble ... I have updated my answer with more info

Answer (score 1):

Recently run into a similar problem on my local environment after an ubuntu update and php 7.2 became my default version.

### make 7.1 or lower your default php version

I believe you should make php 7.1 the default or perhaps even a lower php version for Drupal 7 installation as not all modules are ready for php 7.2 (even some of Drupal 8 modules are not ready for php 7.2)

type this in your shell

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

and this is what you will get

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Choose the appropriate version

### might need to update drush to a later version.

8.1.16 is out at this moment and might already have solved the problem you describe. Update using [composer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222188/updating-drush-with-composer)

### alternatively you can try to setup drush without composer

```
# get drush latest 8 version from 
# https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.16/drush.phar

# make it executable
chmod +x drush.phar;

# move it to home directory or any other directory
mv drush.phar ~/drush;

# go to that directory
cd ~

# find out the path to the directory
pwd
# the output would look similar to this
# /home/your_user

# edit the following file 
nano .bashrc
# or 
# nano .bash_profile

# add this the end of the file
alias drush='/home/your_user/drush';

# use the alias you just setup
source ~/.bashrc;
```

### might want to specify site directory when you invoke drush

as you drush might have a messed up setup/aliases

```
drush status -r /path/to/site/rootdir
```

### doublecheck your settings.php

Does it include the correct database connections? Does the site actually run with those connection settings ?

### Look in your logs for any problems

in my system I can see apache errors like this

```
tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

You might discover that some apache packages are missing or disabled just an example lets say mod_rewrite is not enabled

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or you might find that some package is missing like mysql-client

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Comment: I dropped PHP down to 5.6 and that eliminated my first problem described above...  However, `drush sql-connect` and `drush cc all` still return the same error... can't find the database...  good solid progress.. @GiorgosK thanks

Comment: Posted a few more things to try out.

Comment: Thx for your help, one more step to get drush working.  I located my LAMP mysql socket @  `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  but I can't figure out to point drush to find it.... any thoughts would be greatly useful... everything on the web is MAMP, not LAMP instructions

Comment: drush is driving me nuts... slowing me down.  From my original post whenever I run `drush sql-connect` I still get the same error... I am running from inside the actual drupal folder.  I checked the error log and double checked that rewrite and mysql-client were both installed/working..  I even tried point to the mysql socket using settings.php `'unix_socket'='path/to/socket'`, still no luck..  get to this to work and my lamp is perfect...banging head on wall now.. ;-|

Comment: Thanks for the help... I figured out what was wrong... I completely uninstalled global drush via composer... and installed drush to the us in folder... but I noticed instead of running 8.1.16, I was still running 8.1.13 so I went to the home/vendor and deleted the drush folder there... everything now works perfectly... thx for the assist... your alternative method worked

Comment: would you mind if added you on facebook?  I have some basic questions time to time, but some reason I can't post any more questions here... my project will -astonish- you...

Comment: @yupthatguy go ahead

Comment: of course, I can't add you (security setttings).. I can only message you via FB so I did that...  send me a friend request and we can go from there.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue, and for us it turned out that Drush 8 relies on several packages being installed on the server. In our case, we needed mysql-client to be installed.